PostgreSQL, case sensitive EXECUTE
The EXECUTE statement does not recognize upper case letters on the database name.
Running the below query on a database named "ABcdeFG"
DO
$c$
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'ALTER DATABASE ' || current_database() || ' SET client_encoding = $$LATIN1$$';
END;
$c$;

returns the following error:
"ERROR:  database "abcdefg" does not exist
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "ALTER DATABASE ABcdeFG SET client_encoding = $$LATIN1$$"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at EXECUTE

********** Error **********

ERROR: database "abcdefg" does not exist
SQL state: 3D000
Context: SQL statement "ALTER DATABASE ABcdeFG SET client_encoding = $$LATIN1$$"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at EXECUTE"

Is there a way for this command to be executed considering the upper and lower case letters in the database name, as informed?

Read Identifiers.

You can use the quote_ident function to quote the database name, which will preserve the case.
DO
$c$
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'ALTER DATABASE ' || quote_ident(current_database()) || ' SET 
client_encoding = $$LATIN1$$';
END;
$c$;


It worked by puting the database name in quotes:
DO
$c$
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'ALTER DATABASE "' || current_database() || '" SET client_encoding = $$LATIN1$$';
END;
$c$;


Advice: Create a habit of protecting yourself against SQL injection. You will be safe now, but that's just luck because of this statement. With other statements you might be not so lucky.
